# DD-WRT print server is working on Linux, but not on Windows

Tags: linux, networking, router, printing, dd-wrt

So I flashed the latest DD-WRT on my router, but I can't for the love of God make printing working on Windows. It works seamlessly on Linux though, with [the following settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyyEf.png).

When I add the printer on Windows by adding the 192.168.1.1:9100 address to the TCP/IP field, the printer actually makes some sound (like the one when I turn it on), and it seems that I added the printer, but when I try to print the test page, nothing happens.

---

So here's how I add the printer on Windows: Devices and Printers > Add printer > Add a wireless or Bluetooth printer > The printer that I want isn't listed > Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname > "192.168.1.1:9100", *uncheck* query to automatically select driver > Printer makes noise > Protocol is RAW > I select the driver provided by Samsung (ML-1640, 64 bit) > I press the button to print a test page, but nothing happens, and I can't print anything else either.

Comment: Please provide full details of how you added it in Windows -- type of driver, port and configuration, etc.

Comment: Well, I used the driver that Samsung provided, and as I said, I used port 9100, pretty much everything else is default. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyPk9dT3J54).

Comment: Raw or LPR?  You're not including enough information to give yourself a good likelihood of getting an answer here ... and directing people to watch the tutorial you watched is not really adequate. I'm surprised your question hasn't been down-voted yet for the lack of information.  You need to include full details to make it a self-contained question that could actually be answered without wild guessing based on assumptions.

Comment: Since RAW is the default setting, it is set to RAW, I checked it like 30 times.

Comment: Comment stands: If you want an informed answer, edit your question to provide the FULL DETAILS so that someone has a chance of actually providing an answer.  See http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask , particularly "if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer."

Comment: All right, I edited the post. Detailed enough?

Comment: Probably not, if it hasn't gotten any responses. When you added it, what did you choose under devicetype? Did you put the 9100 in the "hostname or IP address" field or did it detect the TCP/IP port?  Does Samsung say to use LPR or RAW? Did you try setting devicetype manually to "Samsung printer" instead of "custom" (assuming you used "custom")? Is it a PCL5, PCL6, or Postscript driver, and did you try another driver?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DD-WRT wiki](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Printer_Sharing):

> **Windows XP**
>
> Find your printer in Control Panel - Printers etc. and open the
>   properties page for it. Select the Ports tab. Click Add Port and
>   choose Standard TCP/IP printer port and click New Port Enter you
>   router's IP address (normally 192.168.1.1) and click Next Set Device
>   type to custom and click settings. Make sure RAW is selected and
>   specify the necessary port number (normally 9100, 9101 for second
>   printer, etc) and click OK Click Next and Finish and Close Make sure
>   the newly created port is selected for your printer and click OK.

[image: Win7-tcp/ip-printer]
Judging by your question, I'm assuming you entered the IP Address **AND** the port number in the field for the IP address.  It's actually simpler than that, as the above-outlined quote explains.  In other words, only type in the IP address of the print server; i.e. `192.168.1.1`.  Then, wait for Windows to try to do its thing automagically and fail before you click on the *Custom* settings for the port configuration.

[image: Win7-tcp/ip-printer-custom_port_settings]

The port number is indicated in a separate field.

[image: Win7-tcp/ip-printer-port]